# Remove padding from chartist.js charts

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

I would like to have my **[chartist charts](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/)** on my website with no padding from left or right. I am using **`chartPadding: 0`** as advised on several websites, but that did not really help. There is still too much air from the left or right border.

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeq3da7p/). Help would be great!

```js
var chart = Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', {
  labels: ['1.58', '2.58', '4.58', '5.2', '3.1'],
  series: [
    [12, 9, 7, 8, 5],
    [2, 1, 3.5, 7, 3],
    [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  ]
}, {
  showPoint: true,
  showLine: true,
  fullWidth: true,
  showLabel: false,
  axisX: {
    showGrid: false,
    showLabel: true,
    offset: 50
  },
  axisY: {
    showGrid: false,
    showLabel: false,
    offset: 0
  },
  chartPadding: 0,
  low: 0
});

// Listening for draw events that get emitted by the Chartist chart
chart.on('draw', function(data) {
  // If the draw event was triggered from drawing a point on the line chart
  if(data.type === 'label' && data.axis === 'x') {
    
    // We just offset the label X position to be in the middle between the current and next axis grid
    data.element.attr({
      dx: data.x + data.space / 2
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/master/dist/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/master/dist/chartist.min.js"></script>
<div class="ct-chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put negative values to the `chartPadding` property, but that would not give you the effect you are aiming for.

As you render the chart in a normal `div` the default `width` value is set to `100%`. What you can do as a work around is to restrict the width, so there is less space for the `svg`. This will affect the padding on the left/right.

Here the updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zeq3da7p/3/

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that already with several widths, but as this is responsive charts get cropped here and there. But at least it looks a little better than before. Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: chartPadding: {
        top: 0,
        right:  0,
        left:   0,
        bottom: 0
      },